# Как развернуть запущенный процесс в android?

Tags: java, android, процесс

Добрый день, в андроиде есть панель запущенных процессов (при долгом нажатии на системную кнопку), если выбрать процесс, который запущен, то он будет развёрнут. Как реализовать такое же поведение программно? В моём случае есть notification, который всплывает при получении push сообщения, я хочу при нажатии на него проверять, запущен ли процесс приложения, и если да, то разворачивать, если нет, запускать новый сеанс. Как я могу сделать это?

Comment: Это не панель запущенных процессов, а список последних приложений. Часть приложений в этом списке (если не все) обычно не запущены

Comment: Верно, но тем не менее. Есть ли способ проверить, запущен ли процесс и восстановить приложение если да?

Comment: проверяйте статический instance какого-нибудь Activity, Если он существует, значит приложение запущено.

Comment: смотрите мой ответ ниже

Answer (score 1):

Судя по всему так, где HomeActivity это главная активити:

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
        .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);

Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, HomeActivity.class);

notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
        | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
        notificationIntent, 0);

notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13716784/1159507

Comment: Этот код перезапускает приложение, если оно функционирует, а мне надо, чтобы оно в этом случае разворачивалось

Comment: @iamthevoid а гляньте тут - http://stackoverflow.com/q/31448840/1159507